# Finger touch/press/drag

Tags: java, android

I know that there are listeners for finger touch etc.. but I wonder how I can decet a finger drag up/down/left/right.

Is there any kind of listener for that?or it's some math involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at the [Android Developer Resources](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) sometime.